# how to handle optional input with different formcontrol names

Tags: angular, validation, input

I have 2 radio buttons and to inputs
e.g radio buttons are CNIC and Passport. when i click on CNIC, cnic input is shown and on passport input will appear on `*ngIf` based.
**problem is:** when click on submit form shows not valid because required validation is bind with both inputs

TS:

```
Cnic: ['',[Validators.required]],
    Passport : ['',[Validators.required]],
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row left-div-padding">
          <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" checked  vlaue = "cnic" (click) ="radioChange('cnic')">
          <label class="form-check-label">CNIC</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check left-div-megin">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" value="passport" (click) ="radioChange('passport')">
          <label class="form-check-label" >Passport</label>
        </div>
      </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name= "cnic"placeholder="Cnic" mask = '00000-0000000-0' *ngIf ="selectRadio" 
          formControlName="Cnic" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': displayMessage.Cnic }">
        <span class="invalid-feedback">
            {{displayMessage.Cnic}}
        </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pasport" placeholder="Passport" mask = '00-0000-000'*ngIf ="!selectRadio"
            formControlName="Passport" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': displayMessage.Passport }">
          <span class="invalid-feedback">
            {{displayMessage.Passport}}
          </span>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of radio buttons, you can use one `FormControl` and give them the same `name` attribute. Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-base-setup-1ts8b3?file=src/app/app.component.html), a sample code that can be valid in your use case